# Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException while trying to locate a string

Tags: windows, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1, xamlreader

I'm following [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn263215.aspx) tutorial to create my first Windows app.
I'm at step 3, and if I try to run the applications I get a Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException here

```
<TextBlock x:Uid="messageLabel" x:Name="messageLabel" Text=""></TextBlock>
```

Since I'm not even changing the names from the guide, what is going on?

EDIT 1:
Complete error message

```
Eccezione first-chance di tipo 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException' in App1.exe
Informazioni WinRT: E_UNKNOWN_ERROR [Line: 12 Position: 24]
Eccezione di tipo 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException' in App1.exe non gestita nel codice utente
Informazioni WinRT: E_UNKNOWN_ERROR [Line: 12 Position: 24]
Ulteriori informazioni: The text associated with this error code could not be found.

E_UNKNOWN_ERROR [Line: 12 Position: 24]
```

Comment: That line itself is fine. What else is around it? Is there a "WinRT information: Failed to create a ..." debug message that explains the parse problem?

Comment: I've updated the question with the complete error message :/

Comment: Is that line 12? Mind just showing everything you got on that view so far?

Comment: Ok solved. Visual Studio is in italian so I tried to create also resources for it-IT and works now. Does it mean I have to specify every language of every country I want to support in my app? What if I want english only?